# Method not returning string

Tags: string, methods

I'm writing a method that returns a string for an input of a certain mark. It is given a mark, and then determines the grade that the mark fits into. But it gives me this error:

private String getGrade(int marks) throws Exception{
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This method must return a result of type String

The code is:

```
String a = "A, Well done!";
String b = "B, still room for improvement.";
String c = "C, need to improve a lot!";
String d = "D, you got lucky!";
String e = "You failed, please retake the test!";


if (marks>80 || marks==80){
return a;
} else if (marks>70 && marks<80 || marks==70){
return b;
}else if (marks>60 && marks<70 || marks==60){
return c;
} else if (marks>=50 && marks <60){
return d;
}else if (marks<50){
return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't try to be smart enough to evaluate all of the possible cases and make sure you will always return a string in all of the branches of your conditional.  You need to also have an `else` clause with no `if` that will return a default value (which is a string).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a 'else' at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "A, Well done!";
String b = "B, still room for improvement.";
String c = "C, need to improve a lot!";
String d = "D, you got lucky!";
String e = "You failed, please retake the test!";


if (marks>80 || marks==80){
return a;
} else if (marks>70 && marks<80 || marks==70){
return b;
}else if (marks>60 && marks<70 || marks==60){
return c;
} else if (marks>=50 && marks <60){
return d;
}else{
return e;
}
```

As you didn`t return a value if`if (marks<50)` statement fails although we know here no posiblity of failing but program runs in this manner only use as i have done

Answer (score 0):

You have to put out else here and return a string value , otherwise statement will not execute . Try it, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it may help you.

```
String a = "A, Well done!";
String b = "B, still room for improvement.";
String c = "C, need to improve a lot!";
String d = "D, you got lucky!";
String e = "You failed, please retake the test!";


if (marks>=80){
return a;
} else if (marks>=70) {
return b;
} else if (marks>=60){
return c;
} else if (marks>=50){
return d;
} else {
return e;
}
```

**OR**

```
String a = "A, Well done!";
String b = "B, still room for improvement.";
String c = "C, need to improve a lot!";
String d = "D, you got lucky!";
String e = "You failed, please retake the test!";
String r=""

if (marks>=80){
r=a;
} else if (marks>=70) {
r=b;
} else if (marks>=60){
r=c;
} else if (marks>=50){
r=d;
} else {
r=e;
}

return r;
```

I hope the second one is good because it always have return path and return something to caller.